# Помогите исправить NaN

Tags: javascript, html, html5

После ввода данных в формы результат Sa выдаёт NaN, помогите исправить. В Sa передаются значения Тт1 и Std (формул, которые считаются перед этим). И ещё как тут округлить результаты Тт1 и So до сотых?

[Вот сам код](https://codepen.io/Behemoth0/pen/PodoQjW?editors=1010)

В эту функцию приходят не те значения по ходу:

```js
 function breakWaySa(va, Tp, Tt1, Std,  x) {
   resultSa = Number((Tp - Tt1) * (va / 3.6) + Std);
   SARES[x] = resultSa;
   return resultSa.toFixed(2);
 }
```

Консоль выдаёт:

```
va = 0,
Tp = 1.91,
Tt1 = NaN,
Std = Nan,
x = 'va1'
```

---

Вопрос решил, тему можно закрывать.

Comment: @SwaD, оформил отдельным вопросом)

Comment: `В эту функцию приходят не те значения по ходу` - так отловите этот момент и посмотрите почему они приходят. По приложенному вами фрагменту кода нельзя сделать никаких выводов.

Comment: @T0xee.n17, ссылку прикрепил на весь код, просто именно тут кодом указал где проблема. https://codepen.io/Behemoth0/pen/PodoQjW?editors=1010

Comment: @T0xee.n17,пытался отловить - не удалось, решил спросить

Comment: 1 - Вы работаете с числами, не возвращайте из функций строки(.toFixed - строка), 2- дебажить надо каждую итерацию. Например внутри вашего Math.sqrt рассчитывается отрицательное значение. Нельзя взять корень из отрицательного числа, вот и NaN. Далее не смотрел, что там еще за что цепляется.

Comment: Допустим в примере выше, в вашу функцию в переменную `va` попадает строка...

Comment: @SwaD, но функция, которая считает Тт1 формулу, где корень - она же выдаёт результат по итогу. Я не пойму тогда почему если там отрицательное число в Тт1 выходит под корнем то формула работает а дальше нет

Comment: Ну как бы есть сама суть, что данные не совпадают и результаты не верны. Для начала их надо исправить. Почему у вас в формуле отрицательное значение.... Наверное разгадать сможете только вы. Просто факты из анализа вашего кода и формул.

Comment: @SwaD, Просто я то же Тт1 проверял (как и всë, что считало тут) то Тт1 выдавало в итоге верные значения при разных изначально заданых скоростях Va.

Comment: ¯\(ツ)/¯ есть ваш код и он работает так, как он написан. Может я вводил значения не те(вводил от 1 до 10), но суть не меняет. Ошибка в формате данных и формуле(возможно надо проверять значения до.

Comment: @SwaD, Хорошо, спасибо, будем мучиться дальше(

Comment: Что бы починить вашу `va` замените `TARGET[id] = this.value` на `TARGET[id] = Number(this.value)`. Не очень понятно, почему в предыдущем ответе это не требовалось, но не суть.

Comment: @SwaD, спасибо, но такое как и так работало, но по логике Ваш вариант правки должен быть единственным верным, но, работало и так, это как уже второстепенная проблема после NaN

Comment: @SwaD, формулу Tt1 глянул, в дебагере выдаёт (если вводить скорость 38.5) вот такой результат: <div><span>TT1 при va1(38.5)</span><span>0.9948729125084</span></div> . Если вводить скорость меньше 35 то выдаёт NaN

Comment: [Вот тут уже описывал](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1496329/%d0%9f%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b5-%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-nan?noredirect=1#comment2682858_1496329) - пытаетесь взять корень из отрицательного числа.

Comment: @SwaD, добрый день, наконец-то доделал те формулы (даже сделал лучше), теперь добавляет и Тр как Va)